# IATA codes or full names for airline tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I noticed [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/953/flight-mode-phone-use-banned-on-ryanair-is-this-a-worldwide-phenomenon) was tagged [fr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fr) ([IATA code](http://www.airlinecodes.co.uk/airlcodesearch.asp) for Ryanair), and assumed that was an agreed-upon practice (like tagging airport-specific questions with IATA 3-letter airport codes). I went ahead and tagged [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-does-the-southwest-%20airlines-boarding-process-work) with [wn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wn) only to notice afterwards that it had already been tagged [southwest-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/southwest-airlines), which got me wondering what kind of tags should we use...

Arguably it would be more readable to use tags like [ryanair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ryanair) and [finnair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finnair) instead of [fr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fr) and [ay](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ay), but I guess the codes would work fine too. What do you think?

Comment: Of course, having something like "IATA airline code for Ryanair" in the tag wiki excerpt (which shows up when hovering over the tag) is mandatory if we go with the IATA codes.

Comment: Duplicate of [Should we consider having tags for individual airlines?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-we-consider-having-tags-for-individual-airlines) - having both will only split up the discussion and make it harder to follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please review previous discussion on this theme:

[Should we consider having tags for individual airlines?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-we-consider-having-tags-for-individual-airlines)

[fr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fr) is not valid and needs to be edited, as all short tags for airlines.

Comment: Thanks. I retagged http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/953/583

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this short tags is that they are very ambiguous. fr could be as well be the top level domain for France.

So I would propose to use the full name.