# Please swap these airline tags to make the name the main tag and the 2 letter code the synonym

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, reversed-synonyms

Carrying on from [our second discussion of airline names vs 2 letter iata codes](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/iata-codes-or-full-names-for-airline-tags) could somebody please switch:

- <s>[ci](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ci) and [china-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-airlines)</s>
- <s>[cx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cx) and [cathay-pacific](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cathay-pacific)</s>
- <s>[cz](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cz) and [china-southern-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-southern-airlines)</s>
- <s>[u2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/u2) and [easyjet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easyjet)</s>
- <s>[ua](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ua) and [united-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-airlines)</s>
- [sq](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sq) and [singapore-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singapore-airlines)

Comment: @Diamonds: I added another one to the list if you could fix it please.

Comment: completed that this morning, I believe, if you want to double check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

done:

- [ci](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ci) and [china-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-airlines)
- [cx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cx) and [cathay-pacific](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cathay-pacific)
- [cz](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cz) and [china-southern-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-southern-airlines)
- [u2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/u2) and [easyjet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easyjet)
- [ua](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ua) and [united-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-airlines)

Some problems with counters, but I think this will be solved automatically

Comment: OK sorry if I stomped on your edits, I'm having connection troubles.

Comment: Cyclic reference on ci synonims. I think I did something wrong ^(

Comment: I wouldn't know since that's magic what only you diamonds got and us mere 4kers don't got d-;