# IATA codes or ICAO codes?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

I wanted to raise issues related to a previous discussion topic: [IATA codes or full names for airline tags?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/iata-codes-or-full-names-for-airline-tags) The outcome was we decided airline names should be main tag with IATA codes for them mapped as synonyms. As mentioned in another discussion, [IATA codes can be ambiguous](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-we-consider-having-tags-for-individual-airlines/227#227). [ICAO airline designators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICAO_airline_designator), however, are not - they are unique to each airline and thus prevent ambiguity.

Here are a couple of concerns:

- Should we bother mapping ICAO designators to airline names as tag synonyms? How common is the usage of these among travellers / frequent flyers? (My experience suggests it isn't.)
- Should we stick to using either IATA or ICAO, or keep both?

Comment: Well one factor was that unlike the airport codes, few people are even aware of let alone use the airline codes... even though it's on their ticket. Hey I was one of them! (-:

Comment: I meant FlyerTalk fanatics. They would surely use either/both?

Comment: How many questions do we have about air-companies? Why this theme are raised from time to time?

Answer (score 1):

Without applying either IATA or ICAO codes for airlines we have the following tags in use for airlines:

[aegean-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aegean-airlines)
[aer-lingus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aer-lingus)
[aeroflot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aeroflot)
[aerolineas-argentinas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerolineas-argentinas)
[aeromexico](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aeromexico)
[air-asia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-asia)
[air-baltic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-baltic)
[air-canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-canada)
[air-china](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-china)
[air-france](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-france)
[air-india](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-india)
[airline-alliances](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-alliances)
[air-new-zealand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-new-zealand)
[alaska-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alaska-airlines)
[american-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-airlines)
[ana](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ana)
[asiana-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asiana-airlines)
[boa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boa)
[borajet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borajet)
[british-airways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-airways)
[cathay-pacific](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cathay-pacific)
[china-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-airlines)
[china-eastern](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-eastern)
[china-southern-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-southern-airlines)
[delta-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-airlines)
[dragonair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonair)
[easyjet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easyjet)
[emirates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emirates)
[etihad](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etihad)
[eurowings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurowings)
[finnair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finnair)
[flydubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flydubai)
[frontier-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frontier-airlines)
[goair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goair)
[gulf-air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gulf-air)
[hawaiian-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hawaiian-airlines)
[iberia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iberia)
[icelandair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icelandair)
[israir-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israir-airlines)
[jal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jal)
[jet-airways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jet-airways)
[jetstar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jetstar)
[kingfisher-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingfisher-airlines)
[klm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klm)
[korean-air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean-air)
[lot-polish-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lot-polish-airlines)
[low-cost-carriers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-cost-carriers)
[lufthansa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lufthansa)
[luxair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luxair)
[malaysian-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaysian-airlines)
[norwegian-air-shuttle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-air-shuttle)
[oman-air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oman-air)
[peach-aviation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peach-aviation)
[philippine-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philippine-airlines)
[qantas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qantas)
[qatar-airways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qatar-airways)
[royal-air-maroc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/royal-air-maroc)
[royal-jordanian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/royal-jordanian)
[ryanair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ryanair)
[sas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sas)
[saudi-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saudi-airlines)
[singapore-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singapore-airlines)
[societe-hop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/societe-hop)
[south-african-airways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-african-airways)
[southwest-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/southwest-airlines)
[spicejet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spicejet)
[spirit-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit-airlines)
[swiss](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swiss)
[tam-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tam-airlines)
[thomson-airways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thomson-airways)
[transavia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transavia)
[turkish-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turkish-airlines)
[united-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-airlines)
[us-airways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-airways)
[virgin-atlantic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virgin-atlantic)
[virgin-australia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virgin-australia)
[vueling](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vueling)
[wizz-air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wizz-air)
[wow-air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wow-air)

For your first concern, No and I agree, not common.
For your second concern, No, No, and No.

The existing airline tags seem to work reasonably well - better than many other tag collections on TSE.

Note [air-asia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-asia) is in the process of being renamed [airasia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airasia).

Comment: Well if we're going to bother making *Air Asia* into *AirAsia*, we should make *Malaysian Airlines* into *Malaysia Airlines* and *Delta Airlines* into *Delta Air Lines*.